# How could i add an Applications Option to the left Nautilus pane like Finder on OSX or PCMANFM?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus-elementary

I recently noticed this option in PCMANFM, it works the same way as Finder on OSX, you click on the left pane on Applications and then it opens a selection of categories, click again and the application itself will open.

[image]

How, if possible can i add this functionality to Nautilus?.

Comment: added a picture to complete the question - hope that is ok.

Comment: I did not notice this feature till you mentioned it. I might bring it up on Ayatana :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have to create a bookmark to /usr/share/applications in your nautilus sidebar.

It will Not give you categories, but it will be at least the closest to what you are looking for.

Apart from this you could write a Nautilus extension, if you know a bit of Python.

Comment: Ah i see, if someone could make the extension.. i don't know any python at all :(.

Comment: @UriHerrera: Do you know C? I am not sure I would be good enough with Python to write an extension, and I am better in C++ than C (way better), so I might have to pass on that one :).

Comment: @ Roland actually i don't know any programming xD, i'm a graphics designer, but would it be difficult to make it?.

Comment: @UriHerrera: Not really. There was a wonderful Ubuntu classroom session on python, I can get you a link. It doesn't cover everything, but it should give you some basics. You can also take a look at some other nautilus extensions (there are quite a few in python).

Comment: Ah great, i'll take a look into it.